# Find the value of $w=|x-3|-|x+5|-|-x-4|$, knowing that $1<x<3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I have no idea how to even begin this problem. The answer is $-3x-6$

Comment: _HINT_: For the given domain of $x$, all terms are either non-positive or non-negative. You can break open the bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$1<x<3\implies |x-3|=3-x\,,\,|x+5|=x+5\,,\,\,|-x-4|=x+4\;\text{(why?), so...}$$

By the way, you don't find " a value for $\;w\;$" , just an expression depending on $\;x\;$ .

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer, could you expand the logic a bit further?

Comment: I got it now, no need to answer. Thanks for the help